# Не появляется кнопка при попытке отправки медиа (куча фотографий)

Tags: python, aiogram

Не появляется кнопка при попытке отправки медиа (куча фотографий). Язык Python, библиотека aiogram, сам код:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda query: query.data == "photos")
async def zamena(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    photos_dir = 'pic/zamena' # Path to the directory with photos
    photos = [filename for filename in os.listdir(photos_dir) if filename.endswith('.jpg')]

    # If you have photos, send them all in one message
    if photos:
        media_group = []
        for photo in photos:
            photo_path = os.path.join(photos_dir, photo)
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Return Home", callback_data="back_to_start")
            markup.row(btn1)
            media_group.append(
                types.InputMediaPhoto(media=open(photo_path, 'rb'), caption="Your caption here", reply_markup=markup))

        await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id,
                                   media=media_group)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id,
                               text="Could not find photos.")

    await state.finish()
```

Comment: проблема должна быть описана в тексте вопроса, а не в заголовке. см. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Вы уверены, что кнопку необходимо прикреплять к каждому фото? Раз уж отправляете группой, то, вероятно, стоит кнопку отправлять одну на всю группу. Я не знаком с *Telegram API* настолько, чтобы ответить точно, но мне кажется, что проблема в том, что я описал выше

Comment: При попытке: await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, media=media_group, reply_markup = markup) выкидывает в ошибку: TypeError: Bot.send_media_group() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reply_markup'